# Capture url of downloads started by browser in android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

i want to be able to capture url of files being downloaded in browser so that i am able to start downloading from my own app.....after capturing the url i know we need to use the  DownloadManager given here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html to start the Download but is there any broadcast receiver or service i could use to listen when the Download is **started** and get url of that Download

Answer (score 0):

I think you need intent filter : try something like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.package.SampleActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.kdb" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

More info : [here](http://google.com/#q=android+download+with+intent+filter) :)